# Will the expanding cube look gray?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Consider the tiling of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by unit cubes centered at integer lattice points, i.e.

$$ \mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{Z}^n} Q\left(a, \frac{1}{2}\right). $$

Color each unit cube black or white randomly with equal probability. If we now place a block $R$ of arbitrary size on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let it expand, will it look gray in the limit, i.e. will the proportion of black squares to white squares be almost surely 1?

Formally, suppose $(X_a)_{a \in \mathbb{Z}^n}$ is an array of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables indexed by $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Let $R \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary cube. Denote by $\lambda R$ the set $\{\lambda x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \in R \}$ and define the average

$$ S_\lambda = \frac{1}{|I_\lambda|} \sum_{a \in I_\lambda} X_a $$

where $I_\lambda = \mathbb{Z}^n \cap \lambda R$. Does $S_\lambda$ converge almost surely to $1/2$ as $\lambda \to \infty$? More generally, I would like to let $(X_a)_{a \in \mathbb{Z}^n}$ be an arbitrary integrable i.i.d. sequence of random variables. Do the averages converge to $\mathbb{E}[X_a]$ almost surely?

The Strong Law of Large Numbers cannot be applied directly, since the index sets $I_\lambda$ are not monotone increasing with respect to set inclusion. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: The problem looks translation invariant, can you not assume wlog that the cube $R$ is centered at $(0,\ldots,0)$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I considered it but I am not sure if it works. If you let $R_0$ be the cube centered at $0$ having the same size as $R$ and denote the corresponding averages by $\bar{S}_\lambda$, then the sequences $(S_\lambda)$ and $(\bar{S}_\lambda)$ behave differently. For instance, $S_{\lambda_0}$ and $S_{\lambda_1}$ are independent whenever $\lambda_0 R \cap \lambda_1 R$ is empty. On the other hand $\bar{S}_{\lambda_0}$ and $\bar{S}_{\lambda_1}$ are never independent. I do not know if this is a serious obstacle though. I am not very knowledgeable about probability theory.

Comment: Intuitively, the Law of Large Numbers shouldn't rely on the dependence among the different averages in the sequence, because any given average eventually makes an insignificant contribution to later averages. Looking at the proof of the Strong LLN on Wikipedia, I don't think it uses the fact that the same variable can contribute to multiple of the sums at all; it's just the growing *number* of independent summands that ensures the desired convergence.

Comment: @Karl I agree that with the added condition on 4th moments, the proof of SLLN on Wikipedia does generalize to more general averages. But in the case that the random variables merely have finite expectation, the proofs I have seen do rely on the fact that the summands repeat. For example, this happens when one first proves a.s. convergence along a subsequence and then deduces convergence along the entire sequence. If the index sets for the averages are disjoint, convergence along a subsequence would not lead to information on the entire sequence.

Comment: That makes sense! I've been trying to think of a proof of the "arbitrary index sets" version of SLLN from the usual SLLN. (I think this generalization of SLLN is what your question is really about. The growing cube stuff is a bit of a distraction, especially since "expanding" usually doesn't imply translation, so readers will probably assume monotonicity. I suggest making a clarifying edit.)

Comment: @Karl I did ask that question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4816573/strong-law-of-large-numbers-for-increasing-index-sets). But that was hopelessly too general. I managed to solve the case of the expanding cube though. I will post my answer soon.